# Cant get a path finding algorithm to work correctly in all cases

Tags: c#, algorithm, path-finding

I am having trouble with an assignment about finding the shortest total path in a grid, while visiting all the correct tiles in the correct order.

We are supposed to emulate manually inputting a word, like when using a controller to write something, and find the least amount of commands (up, down, left, right) needed to do so.

Our input is the grid, parameters, and the word we are supposed to work with.
I store them like this (with example inputs):

```
 Height = 2;
 Width = 2;               
 Content = "ABCC";
 Word = "ABC";

 grid = new char[Height, Width];
 Contents = Content.ToCharArray();
 Words = Word.ToCharArray();

 int ch = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
   {
     if (ch < Contents.Length)
     {
       grid[i, j] = Contents[ch];
       ch++;
     }
   }
 }
```

The actual way I compute the shortest path is like so:

```
public void GridSearch( int a, int FirstX, int FirstY, int PathLength)
{
  int NewPath;
  int NewX;
  int NewY;
  int SecondX = 0;
  int SecondY = 0;    

  for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
    {
      if (grid[i, j] == Words[a])
      {
        SecondX = i;
        SecondY = j;
        NewPath = PathLength;
        NewPath += Math.Abs(FirstX - SecondX);
        NewPath += Math.Abs(FirstY - SecondY);
        NewX = SecondX;
        NewY = SecondY;
        if (a < Words.Length-1)
        {
         GridSearch(a+1, NewX, NewY, NewPath);
        }
        else
        {
          if (FinalPath > NewPath ^ FinalPath == -1)
        {
          FinalPath = NewPath;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We are also supposed to "click" when on the correct tile, so I am adding the length of "Words" to the total of commands.
In this case, the shortest path between the letters would be 2 (right, down) and the length is 3, so 5 is the correct answer.

This is also what my program gets, however when I try to send it in, the automated checker says it only passes 1 out of **5** tests, which is an improvement over the 0 that I had until recently, but still not actually good.

Sadly it does not say which inputs it used to make my program fail, and after a day of trying things I am out of ideas on how to fix it, could anyone please point out the, no doubt, obvious mistake I am making and help me fix this program?

EDIT: The assignment instructions as written (since a commenter asked for them):

> Some devices allow text entry using a grid of letters.  The grid
> contains a movable cursor, which begins in the upper-left-hand corner.
> Arrow keys move the cursor up, down, left and right and Enter key
> chooses the letter under cursor.
>
> For example, if the input grid looks like this:
>
> ABCDEFGH
>
> IJKLMNOP
>
> QRSTUVWX
>
> YZ
>
> we can enter the text "HELLO" with the following sequence of keys
> (which is only one of many possible sequences):
>
> right
>
> right
>
> right
>
> right
>
> right
>
> right
>
> right
>
> Enter
>
> left
>
> left
>
> left
>
> Enter
>
> down
>
> left
>
> Enter
>
> Enter
>
> right
>
> right
>
> right
>
> Enter
>
> Write a program that for a given grid (which may contain both
> lowercase and uppercase letters) and text (which may also contain
> non-alphabetic characters) determines and writes out the minimum
> number of keystrokes required to enter the given text.
>
> Caution: Each letter may appear more than once in the grid!
>
> The input begins with numbers indicating the width and height of the
> grid (each on its own line).
>
> A single line follows containing the contents of the entire grid (in
> row-major order, i.e. with one row after another).
>
> The rest of the lines contain the text to be entered. ! You should
> ignore any characters in the text that are not present in the grid.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>
> 3
>
> 3
>
> ABCBFECDF
>
> ABCDEFA
>
> Output:
>
> 15
>
> In this example, the grid has the form
>
> ABC
>
> BFE
>
> CDF
>
> It is possible to enter the text ABCDEFA in many possible ways; 15
> keystrokes is the length of the shortest of these.

Comment: `however when I try to send it in, the automated checker says it only passes 1 out of 5 tests` is that a public accessable web page? where we can have a look at the requirements?

Comment: It is not publicly accessible, but I can edit in the requirements.

Comment: As we also do not know the test cases, I can only recommend you to come up with your own test cases and check if they are all passed. (especially corner cases)

Comment: Oh I do have a few, but the problem is that they all pass (now at least), though maybe I did not try enough of them, I have:
Simple line grid,
Grid with symbols,
Grid with repeating letters,
Grid with circling answer,
Repeating answer

Answer (score 1):

Revising my previous answer, it is likely that you have not counted the "enter" keystroke. I.e. you should add one to the candidate path length for each letter:

```
...
NewY = SecondY;
**NewPath++;**
if (a < Words.Length - 1)
...
```

This gives a correct length of 15 keypresses on your example set of "ABCBFECDF" / "ABCDEFA".

Note that this type of code greatly benefits from a type that represents a pair of x/y coordinate, like a `Point` or `Vector2i`, so you don't have to repeat a bunch of calculations for both x and y coordinates. I would also recommend following common coding conventions like

- declare local variables in the smallest possible scope, not at the top of the method
- Use "camelCasing" for local variables
- Prefer pure methods whenever possible, i.e.

I would still recommend reading up on [Djikstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or A*, since these should be more generally applicable and be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am just not sure about one thing.
It is scanning to find the first letter, then after finishing that path and noting its length, it goes back to check the rest of the table for the letter, and finishing that path and so on and so forth.
So this shouldn't be the problem I think?
In the end, it checks (or at least it *should* check) all the possible paths this way and pick the shortest.

I will also check out Point and Vector later, thank you.

Comment: @CodeAche good point, I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thank you for another detailed answer, sadly however the problem is not with counting the "Enter" keystroke, as I do that in my Main function (along with printing the answer).
I did however change it just in case, but it is still resulting in the same 1/5 tests.
I also changed my variables, as that does make much more sense, and will look into Points and Vectors.